# JVM Crash: Problematic frame C [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x4caf] _os_lock_corruption_abort+0x0

Tags: java, jvm, smartcard, smartcard-reader, iaik-jce

```
    import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module;
    import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_SLOT_INFO;
    import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Connector;
    import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception;
    import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Testt {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PKCS11Exception, InterruptedException {

            PKCS11Implementation pkcs11Module_ = (PKCS11Implementation) PKCS11Connector.connectToPKCS11Module(System.mapLibraryName("****"));

            pkcs11Module_.C_Initialize(null, true);
            //System.out.println(moduleInfo);
            long[] slotsWithToken = pkcs11Module_.C_GetSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.TOKEN_PRESENT);
            //for (final long slota : slotsWithToken) {
            final CK_SLOT_INFO ckSlotInfo = pkcs11Module_.C_GetSlotInfo(1l);


            System.out.println(ckSlotInfo);

            pkcs11Module_.C_Finalize(null);


        }
    }
```

When I run the above code, hs_err_pid*.log file is generated. And its content is follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fff8fe14caf, pid=1035, tid=2563
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b17) (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x4caf]  _os_lock_corruption_abort+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread is native thread

siginfo: si_signo: 4 (SIGILL), si_code: 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), si_addr: 0x00007fff8fe14caf

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000020534341, RBX=0x0000000000019000, RCX=0x00000000ffffffff, RDX=0x0000000129716000
RSP=0x0000000109ab8d38, RBP=0x0000000109ab8d70, RSI=0x000000012995e9a0, RDI=0x000000012995e9a8
R8 =0x0000000109ab8e50, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000cb8, R11=0x00007fff8fecd764
R12=0x00000000ffffffff, R13=0x0000000000000002, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x000000012995e9a8
RIP=0x00007fff8fe14caf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010217, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x0000000000000006
```

How can I fix this? My OS is Mac Yosemite and I am using java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: The assumption here is that you encountered this on OS X. Details like this, along with the exact VM version, are going to be instrumental in finding a solution.

Comment: So, "illegal opcode" when loading a dylib. Is it crashing at mapLibraryName()? You could add println debugging to see how far it gets, and split some of those compound lines up. Are you /really/ supposed to pass it a string like "*****"? The problem here is that some native code, probably not in the VM, is doing something Very Bad, and the kernel is killing it. I suspect you have some bad libraries, are using them wrong, or they are for some other system, or there is a bug in the VM (unlikely).

Comment: **** is a valid library name. Just I do not want to give its name.

Comment: If the crash is at the loadLibrary()/mapLibraryName(), and this library is generated by you, it appears to not be a correct library for this architecture.

Comment: Have you find the solution for this? I am having the same problem and nothing works.

Comment: I executed "ulimit -c unlimited" before I ran my code.